# Facebook interest lists always empty?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read many questions here on this site and read the documentation [Facebook Interest List](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/interests) but none really provided an answer to my need.

My problem is that whenever i try to get the Interest List i get empty results and in the questions i read it was to one of the following reason:

1-You need a permission for the user_interest
2-No interest lists

I have two Interest List and as for permissions:

[image]

When i use the Graph API, here is my results:

[image]

So am i making a mistake here or does that mean that it's a bug from Facebook, if anybody have any knowledge about this, please share because i have been struggling with this fro quite sometime.

Comment: So, you're sure that you should have data displayed there? I'm asking because apparently FB has removed the interests from its frontend, at least for my user I can't find anything. Although I can request my interests with `/me/interests`. General question: Why don't you use the likes endpoint, instead of interests? I'll bet that interests will be removed soon.

Comment: I am not sure if the likes and the interests are the same, basically interests list is a list that i create that will contains feeds from all the groups i select. Can the same thing be done with likes and if so how ?

Comment: Interests are more or less outdated. They are, as I said, not really visible anymore on the FB website, at least when I check for my user, whereas the likes are (and probably will ever be). The endpoint for likes is `/{user_id}/likes`, and you'll need the `user_likes` permission.